# Problem with sending multiple mails per SMTP connection with Zend_Mail and Exim

Tags: zend-mail, exim

I have exim mailserver on my dedication server.
I'm trying to send about 800 mails at once with zend_mail
But only about 200 of them sending
I have no php errors in error_log
I tried to log if it too slow and exceed max time execution

```
2010-10-12 15:16:32 - Going to send 795 letters
2010-10-12 15:16:37 - 100 letters done
2010-10-12 15:16:41 - 200 letters done
```

And then nothing. I can't find how to catch the error throwed by Zend_Mail. So i looked in exim_mainlog and found there some errors near this time

```
1P5cDN-0000fo-27 no immediate delivery: more than 10 messages received in one connection
H=localhost [127.0.0.1] Warning: Sender rate 479.5 / 1h
```

Does it mean i should interrupt connection every 10 letters or I have to change some cofig for exim?
The main problem is - i can't test a lot, because my subscriber got tests mails and if i test with a few mails it works fine

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with Zend_Mail, but with the Exim configuration. The default number of delivery processes that Exim starts when receiving messages via SMTP is 10. This is controlled by the configuration option **smtp_accept_queue_per_connection**

http://wiki.exim.org/FAQ/General_Debugging/Q0049

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html